# Plotting time with flot, json series

Tags: javascript, json, flot

JSON data is not being plotted?

Javascript:

```
var datasets = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);                
alert(JSON.stringify(datasets[0]));

var plotarea = $("#placeholder");
$.plot(plotarea, [[datasets[0].points]], {
    xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        min: (new Date(2013, 11, 1)).getTime(),
        max: (new Date()).getTime()
    }
});
```

Outputs:

```
{"name":"Test.txt","points":[[1389313796000,2],[1389314796000,4]]}
```

Rendered graph:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got one too many sets of `[` `]` on the data argument in your plot call.  Should be:

```
$.plot(plotarea, [datasets[0].points], {
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/zCuQ5/1/).

Even with that fixed though, your "plot" is just a vertical line on the right grid border.

[image]

Comment: nice one! altering the epoch's i see sloped data too